# Javascript Variable Change Conundrum

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have this little loop which checks the id of the last div on my page and then replaces the div with a rendered updated div using ajax, then loops around and repeats. Now the problem I have is that if it loops and the id of the last div is the same it just adds another updated div so I get two of the same thing. I would only want it to append the data again if the id of the last div has changed (i.e it's a different div), but I don't think Javascript has  an onChange method for calling the request only when id has changed. How might I go about this in JS?
Thanks in advance.

```
$( window ).load(function() {
    update_live();
});

function update_live (){
    var id = $(".tasktable").last().attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/ansible_jobs/update_live/",
        data: { task_id: id },
        dataType: 'html',
        success: data_append
    });}

function data_append(data){
        $('.tasktable').last().empty();
        $('.tasktable').last().replaceWith(data);
        setTimeout(update_live, 2000);
    }
```

Comment: ajax is asynchronous so if you loop ajax, it'll do everything at the same time

e,g,

for(i=0; i<2; i++) {
  some ajax...
}

it'll loop twice at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change update_live() to update_live(previousId), compare it with the current one, and update only if it is different. Pass the id forward.

Comment: I thought about that but I realised it would be a problem with the initial div as the loop would never be initialised, anyway I've managed to get it working now a different way but thanks anyway!